# How to notate correctly a vector storing four 3-dimensional matrices in mathematics?

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

How to notate correctly a vector storing four 3-dimensional matrices in mathematics? For example, 4 images are stored in a vector and each of these matrices has three dimensions like  and RGB image (RED, GREEN, BLUE).

Comment: In mathematics we can write $v=(A,B,C,D)$ with four matrices of any size. We can view any matrix as a vector, and just combine the components.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not sure if I can capitalize the members of the vector to indicate they are matrices.

Comment: How can I also indicate they are three dimensional (A,B...,D)?

Comment: You can write $A=(a_1,\ldots ,a_9)$, and so on, so that $v=(a_1,\ldots ,a_9,b_1,\ldots ,b_9,\ldots, \ldots ,d_1,\ldots ,d_9)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have been trying to accept your answer but the "tick" does not appear.

Comment: If you want I can write my comment as an answer. There you can tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to represent a $3\times 3$ matrix as an vector in $K^9$, i.e., by
$A=(a_1,\ldots ,a_9)$. Then we can represent $4$ matrices of size $3$ by a vector
$$
v=(a_1,\ldots,a_9,b_1,\ldots ,b_9,c_1,\ldots c_9,d_1,\ldots ,d_9)\in K^{36}.
$$